# Wireguard VPN Client GUI

Tags: server, network-manager, vpn, gui, wireguard

I have already running 12 WireGuard VPN Servers.
Now I want to use an application to manage the connection on the clients.
On my Arch-Linux Client I have the `network-manager-wireguard` plugin running and its working fine.

Is there any WireGuard GUI for Ubuntu?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and already tried to compile this https://github.com/max-moser/network-manager-wireguard myself, but I ran into the following error during `./autogen.sh`:

```
checking for LIBNM_GLIB... no
configure: error: Package requirements (NetworkManager >= 1.2.0
    libnm-util >= 1.2.0
    libnm-glib >= 1.2.0
    libnm-glib-vpn >= 1.2.0) were not met:

No package 'NetworkManager' found
No package 'libnm-util' found
No package 'libnm-glib' found
No package 'libnm-glib-vpn' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBNM_GLIB_CFLAGS
and LIBNM_GLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

But, I can't find the packages `libnm-util`, `libnm-glib` and `libnm-glib-vpn` in the package repositories.

Is there any known solution for this? I even can't find anything helpful on Google.

Or, is there at least any other simple way to connect to multiple WireGuard VPN Servers from an Ubuntu 20.04 Client?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I finally found a way to get it working on Ubuntu 20.04. Here are the steps you need to do. Maybe this will help someone in the future:

Install the needed packages to build and use the plugin:

```
sudo apt install wireguard git dh-autoreconf libglib2.0-dev intltool build-essential libgtk-3-dev libnma-dev libsecret-1-dev network-manager-dev resolvconf
```

Clone the plugin from github, compile and install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/max-moser/network-manager-wireguard
cd network-manager-wireguard
./autogen.sh --without-libnm-glib

./configure --without-libnm-glib --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager --localstatedir=/var

make   
sudo make install
```

Comment: I followed your commands and as far as I know they all succeeded succesfully. But I don't see any mention of Wireguard in the UI yet. Once installed, where can I find the installed GUI? What am I supposed to see where? Screenshots would be awesome.. :-)

Comment: You can find it under Settings -> Network. Click then on the + behind "VPN". Now there should be the Option Wireguard.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately there is no such option for me. So I suppose something went wrong with the install. I'll try to do it again.

Comment: Did you succeed in this since then? If so, what did you do to achieve that result?

Comment: AUR package (not on ubuntu) which does the same thing, seems to work but the config importer doesn't recognize WireGuard configs, so it seems kind of useless... in KDE the built-in GUI seems to do a much better job

Comment: Working good. Thank you.

Comment: Works for me too!

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04 I followed its commands and I can see the wireguad options in the GUI, I can configure my vpn and I can activate it, but the wireguard VPN never starts, even though the GUI says it is running

Comment: Wish this came by default in 21.10, but thanks this works on 21.10

Comment: Not working in 22.04 . When attempting to activate it results in "Activation of Network Connection Failed" and no connection made to the server.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404807/wireguard-management-in-network-manager-on-jammy .

Comment: Installing libgtk-3-dev messed a bunch of my nvidia driver dependencies and couldn't get my monitor to be recognized. Is there another way to get gtk3 without all the other packages apt installs? Seems like there is a conflict with the nvidia proprietary drivers.