# Working VPN connection but can't access my samba share

Tags: networking, samba, vpn

I am using Wireguard VPN to connect my work laptop to my home network where I have files stored on Samba share. Both the VPN and the share are installed on my Raspberry PI (with a static ip).

Now the issue is that I cannot access the samba share on the network, but can browse the internet just fine. I also have a peer on my android phone and the samba share seems to work just fine there -> leading me to conclude that VPN is working fine and there is a problem with my Ubuntu laptop.

In order to connect to VPN I use some makeshift wireguard gui (followed tutorial on https://askubuntu.com/a/1233341/1476346). Since internet works fine I figured that maybe my laptop is only partially routing traffic trough VPN, but the rest (network sharing service) is routed through the default adapter (PCs on wifi at work show up despite having my vpn turned on).

Routing table (PC is the VPN interface):

```
Destination    | Gateway     | Genmask      | Flags | Metric | Ref | Use | Iface 
default        192.168.212.80  0.0.0.0        UG      600      0       0   wlp2s0
10.6.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0  U       50       0       0   PC
link-local     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0    U       1000     0       0   wlp2s0
192.168.212.0  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0  U       600      0       0   wlp2s0
```

Does anyone have an idea to what might be wrong / how I may fix it?
Ubuntu version: 20.04LTS - ElementaryOS 6

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: Can you add the text for the routing table into the question? The picture is very hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Do you have control of the VPN server? You probably need to change its config file to push the local subnet to the client.  See https://blog.bobbyallen.me/2016/02/07/enabling-openvpn-clients-to-access-to-the-lan/